# Androidviewclient valueError while running

Tags: android, linux, python-2.7, androidviewclient

I have generated the template using command $ culebra -U -o mytest.py and using for com.csr.csrmeshdemo:id/powerSwitch to turn on and off the switch.
It worked fine for first time but after restarting system for another issue I am unable to run my python script. getting error like this:

```
*root@parameshwar:~/Desktop/monkey/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/CSR_script# adb devices
List of devices attached 
T00940ZEIM  device
root@parameshwar:~/Desktop/monkey/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/CSR_script# python t6.py 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t6.py", line 44, in testSomething
    self.vc.dump(window='-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.6-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 3270, in dump
    self.setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.6-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 2927, in setViewsFromUiAutomatorDump
    self.__parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump(received)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/androidviewclient-11.5.6-py2.7.egg/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py", line 3109, in __parseTreeFromUiAutomatorDump
    raise ValueError("received does not contain valid XML data")
ValueError: received does not contain valid XML data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.508s
FAILED (errors=1)*
```

Please help me with this..

Comment: Try running `uiautomator dump` in `adb shell` and verify if the output is correct.

Comment: Also, if you upgrade to **11.5.7** the information provided will be more descriptive about the problem

Comment: Thanks for help!! The problem occurred with UIAutomator, It is resolved when I restart the mobile phone!!

Answer (score 0):

Latest **AndroidViewClient/culebra 11.5.7** adds more verbose information about the exception and would let you trace the root cause easily.